# A Program for Transfering a folder from a Mac to an Android Phone

Tags: android, macos, bash

I've been trying to write a small program to copy a folder on my mac (10.10.3), containing a set of songs, into the music folder on my Galaxy S3 (GS3) when it is connected via USB. Clearly I could just use Android File Transfer (AFT), and copy the files in (manually), however this wouldn't teach me anything. My goal is thus to automate this act. Python seems like a good choice for this project, as it  seems like mostly scripting (in fact a Bash script may suffice).

This *should* be simple, using a bash script like `cp ~/../music_on_mac /.../music_target_on_android`

However, the file structure of the GS3 doesn't show up in the finder (like you would expect from an ordinary USB drive). I can only see the file structure via Android File Transfer. From what I've read, this is expected behavior (I suppose due to formatting differences?). Thus I've been unable to find the target directory `/.../music_target_on_android`

My best guess (getting a bit out of my depth here), is that I need to copy the music folder, and then pipe it to AFT, and have AFT place it in/on top of the target Music folder on my GS3. Is this correct? If so, could anyone offer suggestions on implementing this? If not, alternative approaches or suggestions would also be appreciated.

I'd also note that I considered using `./adb push <local> <remote>` to try to copy the files directly, however this pushed back that the device was read only. I'm also not familiar enough to find the proper directory on the GS3 (the one containing the target for the "Music" folder) using `./adb shell`. There's also the added downside that in order to use a solution involving the ADT, one must have the ADT (which most people don't). Moreover, I want to keep it simple.

Research Update: 
I've found that my phone will not show up in Finder because Google has disabled USB mass storage (aka mounting the phone as a disk) in favor of the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP). AFT is just an MTP client, needed because unlike Windows and Linux, OSX does not support MTP.
http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/

Based on tips, I've been able to implement an alternative based on creating an FTP server on my phone. Connecting to this gives me file system access and write privileges from my terminal, which is half the battle, however its quite slow. Thus I'd still like to find a way to automate instructions to Android File Transfer.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your phone to the computer when the phone screen is unlocked? I needed to do that when using my Nexus 5. If that works, you might want to check out `rsync`.

Comment: I have tried that. Almost exclusively in fact. It doesn't seem to effect whether or not the android file structure shows up in Finder. I'll check out rsync.

Comment: Any update on this perhaps? I wanted to build something similar :)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The way cloud based services are taking over, this is kind of dated now. For instance, google music/music manager gives you a gigantic cloud storage library for your music. Even better, it constantly syncs with iTunes, uploads new music to the cloud, and automatically downloads to my Galaxy S6. Apple Music now does this too, but they charge for it.